# Auth0 - Callback URL never called

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0

I'm integrating Auth0 to an existing client project, and I am having some trouble with the callback url after login from Auth0.

The issue is that when the callback URL is called, the id_token and the access_token are available only in the hash fragment and not on the query string. To have it available for the server, I would need it in the query string.

My responseType is of type 'code':

```
this.auth0 = new Auth0({
  clientID: clientId,
  domain: domain,
  responseType: 'code',
  callbackURL: 'http://mydevserver:3000/callback'
});
```

So the question is, how can I have id_token and access_token in the query strings?

https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/local-testing-and-development#auth0-and-localhost

Answer (score 2):

Without the actual code you're using we'll have to do a bit of guessing, but the `id_token` and `access_token` are returned on the hash fragment when you're using a response type of `token`. This is aimed for browser-based applications that as a consequence have access to the URL fragment.

If your application is a traditional server-side web application you should be using the `code` response type so that an authorization code is sent to your server-side as part of the query string. Then on the server-side you can issue a request to exchange this code for the actual tokens.

These two types of flows are defined within the OAuth 2.0 specification:

- [Implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) with the `token` response type (aimed at browser-based applications)
- [Authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) with the `code` response type (aimed at confidential clients like server-side web applications)

As a reference, you can follow this documentation in order to accomplish what you mentioned: [Integrating a Web App with Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth-web-protocol)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my question. In fact I am using responseType 'code' but it seems like nothing changes. Is there any other configuration needed in Auth0?

Comment: Ensure that in Auth0 dashboard the client application is configured as a *Regular Web Application* in the *Client Type* setting. If that does not help, share all the code related to the authentication setup. Be sure to remove/replace sensitive information.

Comment: I see that the issue is that on your React documentation, there's responseType on the Login method on the frontend and also on the AuthService middleware. I was just updating one of them to 'code' and didn't see the other one. Thanks again

Comment: Glad this was sorted and yes, that's correct, passing response type to the `login` method will override the value provided to the `Auth0` constructor.